# Running website via Docker on macOS loading images but not on server

Tags: docker, macos, case-insensitive

I run a website via Docker as I develop on macOS and macOS is set up with a case-insensitive filesystem by default.

When I run the site, I was rendering an image with no issues locally via Docker. When I deployed, it didn't work. Upon inspection I found that the image was `This_Is_My_Image.jpg`, yet I was requesting `this_is_my_image.jpg`.

My [incorrect] assumption was that using Docker I would gain the advantage of Linux with it being case-sensitive as default but it seems that the file system is inherited into Docker - meaning that my Docker image (`node:fermium-buster-slim`) is running a file system which is case-insensitive?

My `Dockerfile.dev` is:

```
FROM node:fermium-buster-slim

ARG GID=1000
ARG UID=1000

USER ${UID}:${GID}

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

The production image runs on a Linux system which makes me think that this is the case?

Comment: I've come across this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/320#issuecomment-428656077

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  Which of these Dockerfiles are you using?  I believe the MacOS host file system does _preserve_ case, so for example if you `ls` you'll see files listed with the case they were originally created.

Comment: It's run via Make and through docker compose. The `Dockerfile.dev` is the one used locally. macOS is set up with case-insensitive by default, so Linux seems to inherit that and not throw an error when the wrong casing is used in the network request.

Comment: If the longer `Dockerfile` isn't relevant to your question, you can [edit] the question to delete it.  Conversely, the `docker-compose.yml` seems very relevant, and you should include it.

Comment: Yep, I've removed it - cheers